# How to print HTML entities in Latex using pdflatex

Tags: html, input-encodings, listingsutf8

I've string of HTML entities containing characters in devnagri font. Sample HTML Entity String is :

```
<h1>&#2311;&#2344;&#2346;&#2369;&#2335; &#2360;&#2366;&#2343;&#2344;&#2375; &#2321;&#2344;&#2354;&#2366;&#2311;&#2344; &#2357;&#2366;&#2346;&#2352;&#2370;&#2344; &#2346;&#2361;&#2366;</h1> <p><span>&#2310;&#2346;&#2339; &#2344;&#2367;&#2357;&#2337;&#2354;&#2375;&#2354;&#2381;&zwj;&#2351;&#2366; &#2349;&#2366;&#2359;&#2375;&#2350;&#2343;&#2381;&zwj;&#2351;&#2375; &#2335;&#2366;&#2311;&#2346; &#2325;&#2352;&#2339;&#2375; &#2360;&#2379;&#2346;&#2375; &#2348;&#2344;&#2357;&#2340;&#2366;&#2340;</span></p>
```

I'm looking for LATEX package, which will help to print characters corresponding to HTML Entities using pdflatex. [Sample code to print unicode is mentioned below to show list of packages which I'm already using. Is there any similar way to print HTML Entities]

```
\documentclass[addpoints,answers,10pt]{exam}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{nonfloat}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{questions}
\question[4]
\unichar{"00E4}
\end{questions}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

**xetex: Partial answer**

If you save the html in the question to `temp.html` and look at it in a web browser you can cut and paste the text with the character references expanded. It is then easy to add a bit of TeX markup. (I picked the font that the Windows application "wordpad" picked to show these characters, any other installed font that has them would also work)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Aparajita}
\begin{document}

\section*{इनपुट साधने ऑनलाइन वापरून पहा}

आपण निवडलेल्‍या भाषेमध्‍ये टाइप करणे सोपे बनवतात

\end{document}
```

Processing that with xelatex produces the following. I'm sorry I have no idea if this is even approximately the correct text.

[image]

---

**PDFTeX: Partial answer**

Partial answer, this converts the html character references into `\unichar` calls, but I don't know what packages and fonts you need to actually typeset so I get

```
? ! Undefined control sequence.
<inserted text> ...tdevanagarii \textdevanagarina
```

But perhaps you can use this as a start

```
\documentclass[addpoints,answers,10pt]{exam}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{nonfloat}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[combine]{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\def\zz{\begingroup\catcode`\&\active`\catcode`\#12 \xzz}
\def\xzz#1{#1\endgroup}

\begingroup\lccode`\~`\&\lccode`\+`\#\lowercase{\endgroup\def~#1#2;{\unichar{"#2}}}
\begin{document}


\zz{\textbf{&#2311;&#2344;&#2346;&#2369;&#2335; &#2360;&#2366;&#2343;&#2344;&#2375; &#2321;&#2344;&#2354;&#2366;&#2311;&#2344; &#2357;&#2366;&#2346;&#2352;&#2370;&#2344; &#2346;&#2361;&#2366;}}

\zz{&#2310;&#2346;&#2339; &#2344;&#2367;&#2357;&#2337;&#2354;&#2375;&#2354;&#2381;&zwj;&#2351;&#2366; &#2349;&#2366;&#2359;&#2375;&#2350;&#2343;&#2381;&zwj;&#2351;&#2375; &#2335;&#2366;&#2311;&#2346; &#2325;&#2352;&#2339;&#2375; &#2360;&#2379;&#2346;&#2375; &#2348;&#2344;&#2357;&#2340;&#2366;&#2340;}

\end{document}
```

Comment: To remove error mentioned above we need to add packages mentioned below: \usepackage{devanagari}
\usepackage{devanagaridigits}   After adding these packages PDF is getting generated without error. But generated PDF files is only having ' (Begin Quote) character for each unicode. Can you please help to get respective character instead of ' (Quote)

Comment: @pawanmude there was a missing `"` in the definition (fixed) but I fear it won't work, the comments in the dvanagari package indicate heavy uses of catcodes and a pre-processor. You might be better to expand out the character references to utf8 (any xml parser or even a web browser would do that) and then just use normal tex markup with pdflatex (or xetex might be easier). I'll leave this answer here unless someone posts something better but I suspect you need someone who understands the script.

Comment: @pawanmude updated with a xetex suggestion

Comment: Thanks David for giving direction. I'm using PHP.  I tried to convert HTML from 'HTML-ENTITIES' to 'UTF-8' using :  $html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES'); but somehow it's printing HTML-ENTITIES in tex file. Can you please direct me to any documentation which shows how to print UTF-8 characters in Latex.

Comment: As suggested , Let me try xetex and will update you results.

Comment: @pawanmude really it is _much_ easier to do this if you use xelatex (or lualatex) rather than pdflatex, as I show in my updated question it "just works" as they naturally understand your installed system fonts.

Comment: Sir thanks for helping me, while using xelatex updated solution, I'm getting error as "Missing character: There is no à¤¤ in font cmr10!" this error is getting repeated for each character.

Comment: @pawanmude cmr10 is the classic tex font it only has unaccented latin characters. You need a unicode font with the script in. I chose `\setmainfont{Aparajita}` but any font you have installed in your system should work with xetex.

Comment: Sir, I'm using linux (centos) and it appears that currently there is no font which supports devnagri font. It appears that I need to install nakul.ttf or mangal.ttf to make it work. Is there any document which helps to install mangal.ttf or nakul.ttf on linux box (centos) ?

Comment: @pawanmude it's been a while since I did any font stuff on linux. I would hope that your OS package manager (yum or apt-get or rpm etc would do it for you??) Does your browser not display these characters? If it does you must have _some_ font with them already.

Comment: Yes Sir, My browser displays these characters when fetched from MySQL database. I've also copied magnal.ttf ; but while compiling i'm getting error as : " Package polyglossia Error:
The current roman font does not contain the Devaganari script!
Please define \devaganarifont with \newfontfamily. "

Comment: @pawanmude so you must have a suitable font installed. you can worry about polyglossia later the example above doesn't use that package. You should just need to change `Aparajita` to a font you have installed.

Comment: Sorry Sir, I forgot to tell you, I'm not able to use xetex it's giving me error "! Undefined control sequence." So using xelatex. 
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{polyglossia}
    \usepackage{fontspec}

    \setdefaultlanguage{marathi}
    \newfontfamily\devanagarifont{Mangal}

    \begin{document}
    टाइप करण्याकरता

    \end{document}

Comment: I've downloaded mangal.ttf from http://www.cghs.nic.in/hindiFont.jsp and copied it  /usr/share/fonts/TTF ; somehow system is not able to recognize it.